# Passing args to sh via php. First argument is received but not the second

Tags: php, shell, exec

The first argument `$htmlpageid` can be referenced to by `$1` in the sh script.
The second argument should be referenced by `$2`. Right?

```
<?php
    $htmlpageid = uniqid();
    $days ="1";   
    $command = shell_exec("sudo ./createclientcert.sh $htmlpageid $days");    
?>
```

No matter what i try but i can't get the second argument `$days` over to the script.
I tried several methods but none of them passes the second argument `$days`.

Comment: What's not receiving the 2nd argument?  the URL at mydomain.nl, or is createclientcert.sh not receiving $days from PHP?  (it works just fine here with test scripts)....

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey "or is createclientcert.sh not receiving $days from PHP?" that is exactly what my story tells. ;) i've updated the question to make it less confusing. ;)

Comment: Any error messages?  If you call the script without calling it via sudo, does it pass $2?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey solved it already. Thanks for thinking with me but i made a pretty dumb mistake. I answered the question myself but can accept it as the answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I made i mistake by referencing $days by $2 in the sh script because i referenced it inside a function definition.

Very sorry for this dumb thing. ;)

```
#!/bin/sh
newclient () {
    echo "# valid from "$(date) "till "$(date --date='+'$2' day') >> /root/$1.ovpn
}
```

Instead I should had coded the command outside a function *or* called the function with the arguments passed to the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
newclient () {
    echo "# valid from "$(date) "till "$(date --date='+'$2' day') >> /root/$1.ovpn
}

newclient $1 $2
```